# How do I make a element appear multiple times on my page with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quick question, how do I take the below box:

HTML

```
<div class="box">
I am a box.
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
border: 1px solid green;
}
```

JavaScript

```
let x =
```

and make it appear on my page 4 times?

https://jsfiddle.net/W3Develops/s6v8zafm/3/

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Clone and append

Comment: You can do in js iterations with "for" and return results in html

Comment: Thank you everyone, should I delete this question or leave it here as a link to the other question in case someone else has the same question but doesn't know how to phrase it like the other question?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/go9vL76w/

Comment: I would delete it.

Comment: I edited your original fiddle to give you an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
let box = document.querySelector('.box');
for(let x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    let clone = box.cloneNode(true);
    document.body.appendChild(clone)
}
```

Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/tdx5f6cw/6/

Comment: Mine https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/go9vL76w/10/ ;)

Comment: Thank you Anton this is the perfect answer to my question. I went to the link the community said this was a duplicate of and oh my gosh I was way over my head reading through that documentation, haha I was abut to go back to Google. Thanks again you totally saved the day!

Comment: @mplungjan even better, more readable with maxBox and numBox :D

Comment: @JonathanJackson ah my bad I cloned it, guess I need to republish it to make it visible, anyways good luck!

Comment: Here is the dupe code. It is pretty straight forward `function cloning() {
    var container = document.getElementById('mydiv');
    var clone = document.getElementById('div_0').cloneNode(true);
    clone.setAttribute('id','div_'+document.getElementById('mydiv').getElementsByTagName('div').length);
    container.appendChild (clone);
}` - change container to body and you do not need the line with the ID since you do not have an ID

Comment: @mrplungjan this looks very interesting, I'm about to start Googling some of the terms here that look familiar but that I do not exactly know to gain a better understanding. Thank you very much.